# How to define override services in a shared module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, ecmascript-6

I have a shared module, written in AngularJS 1.6.5. This module is to be used by multiple applications. This module has several services, internally, that must be overridden by the host application. This is to handle things such as request authorization differences to varying REST endpoints, which are all different between the different host systems.

I know that I could define my shared module first, and then define services of the same name later in my code, but this feels very dirty. Especially when each application already has services like this, just under different names.

Any suggestions?

**Clarification:**

So my shared module might have directives with controllers that inject a service

```js
class MyDirectiveController {
  /*@ngInject*/
  constructor($element, entity) {
    this.$element = $element;
    this.entity = entity;
  }
  
  $onInit() {
    this.entity.get(this.id)
      .then((data) => this.dataSet = data);
  }
}
```

And, within the shared module, I would have a dummy service:

```js
class Entity {
  /*@ngInject*/
  constructor($q) {
    this.$q = $q;
  }
  
  get() {
    console.info('You must include your own override service for retrieving entity data');
    return this.$q.reject();
  }
}
```

Then somehow pass my parent app service in as an override to the module's entity service:

```js
entity = MyAppEntityService;
```

Answer (score 0):

The order of service definitions matters only for config phase. For run phase the hierarchy of modules matters (unless there are several definitions of same service within a single module).

Considering that shared module has `foo` service, a module that loads will be capable of overriding its services:

```
angular.module('app', ['shared']).factory('foo', ...);
```

Comment: Trying to avoid this pattern. See my updated question above for some context.

Comment: I see. This is perfectly valid pattern for the case you're having. You can even throw an error in dummy implementation. You could modify existing service with a decorator, but since it should be fully replaced, it doesn't make sense.